# Nhibernate - Update my Customer like this?

Tags: .net, asp.net, nhibernate

i use nhibernate. i got a Customer and Customer got a IList.. now when i add a new Customer and CustomerUser i do like this.

```
var customer = new Customer {
    Name = txtCustomerName.Text,
    OrgNumber = txtOrgNumber.Text
};
var customerUser = new CustomerUser {
    Email = txtUserMail.Text,
    Password = password.Sha1()
};

customer.CustomerUsers.Add(customerUser);
```

Now i want to update the customerUser but how should i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below. If the Id equal the unsaved-value (in your mapping file) an INSERT is done if the Id is not equal the the unsaved-value an UPDATE is done.  Of course, this collection is may be not saved, if the setting in the mapping file is not correct.

```
using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        session.SaveOrUpdate(customer);
        tx.Commit();

    }
    catch (NHibernate.HibernateException ex)
    {
        tx.Rollback();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how you can save your changes? If so you need to use the flush keyword.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean with flush the keyword here? I want to update the customerUser, like change the Email to it or so. Do i need to get the customerUser by id or is it possible to get the customer by id and update the customerUser throught there, if you know what i mean?